# Amazon AWS EC2 or WorkSpaces for 5 users?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rdp

I remotely manage a small company's network half-way around the world. They have 5 local users connecting to their Windows server sessions with RDP to a physical in-house Windows Server, and they want to migrate to cloud computing.

I'm not sure WorkSpaces is the right solution, or if I should just stand up 5 EC2 instances one for each user. But individual instances whether WorkSpaces or EC2 defeats the advantage of a single machine to install applications that are immediately available to all users who connect to their sessions by RDP.

Windows RDS (Terminal Services) licensing requires a dedicated instance on AWS which is very expensive, otherwise I would do that. Windows RDS licensing is not an option for on-demand or reserved EC2 instances.

If you've been down this road before, please let me know what you recommend.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot remote desktop on AWS Workspaces. It is a different model of compute. If you just need your 5 users to access your applications, you can use Workspaces to save TCO. A typical use case for this are call centers where your end-users just need to access the apps.

You pay Workspaces for monthly use whereas EC2 are paid by the hour/year/etc.

Answer (score 0):

Launch a Windows EC2 instance with SQL Server on it. Create 5 users for that server and provide the 5 users RDP access to that server. You can even create that instance in the region that is near to those 5 users.

You will need Client Access License from Microsoft https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/licensing/product-licensing/client-access-license.aspx if you need more than 2 sessions on RDP.

Comment: Windows Servers are limited to 2 RDS  sessions. Does an EC2 instance with SQL Server come with the extra RDS licenses to allow more than 2 RDS sessions?

Comment: Windows Servers, RDS and EC2 are 3 different things? An EC2 instance is a Windows Server and RDS is a dedicated DB service by AWS.

Comment: By RDS I was referring to Remote Desktop Services (aka Terminal Services) in Windows Server. I see what you're referring to with RDS -- in AWS-speak RDS means Relational Database Service.

Comment: Ok now it is clear. i don't think AWS Windows EC2 instance is limited to 2 sessions? We have 8 developers users who use AWS RDP to use the server.

Comment: It's limited to 2 simultaneous sessions. You can have as many users on the server as you want but as soon as you try and get the 3rd session started your remote desktop client will tell you that you already have the maximum 2 sessions.

Try it. I did last week -- I created 5 users on the AWS EC2 instance and had 2 users connect to 2 sessions. The moment I tried to connect a 3rd user to a 3rd session, I got the prompt that only 2 sessions are allowed.

Comment: Do you have a dedicated EC2 instance with extra TS licenses installed? According to AWS, only _dedicated_ EC2 instances or if you have "Microsoft License Mobility with Software Assurance" can you install TS licenses. [Microsoft Licensing on AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/windows/resources/licensing/)

Comment: Yes we have that so I guess you will need to get that license if you want multiple sessions. I

Comment: Thanks for replying. If you know, do you have a **dedicated** EC2 instance (not reserved or on-demand)? Or do you have Microsoft License Mobility with Software Assurance? I think MLMSA is a subscription you pay to Microsoft so you can move your licenses from machine to machine. We purchased TS CL licenses but AWS said they can't be installed on a reserved or on-demand EC2 instance, they can only be installed on a dedicated EC2 instance (dedicated EC2 starts around $1500 per month).

Comment: Yes our EC2 is running on dedicated instance as Microsoft Licensing has issue not to add the license to shared instance. Tell me one thing is some thing hosted on your Windows server? or why are the developers using that in cloud?